Is this an acceptable proof of ${(f∘g)}^{-1}$ = ${g}^{-1}$∘${f}^{-1}$?
Let a, b, and c be any numbers such that
f(b) = c,
g(a) = b
f∘g = f(g(x))
Substituting a for x gives
f(g(a)) = f(b) = c
So, in the inverse of f(g(a)) we must get a inputting c.
Reversing the steps above gives
${f}^{-1}$(c) = b
${g}^{-1}$(b) = a
Substituting the first into the second gives
${g}^{-1}$(${f}^{-1}$(c)) = a
We can see that we get a inputting c, so it is the inverse of f(g(a)).
There is nothing unique with a, b, and c, so we can conclude that the inverse of
f(g(x)) is ${g}^{-1}$(${f}^{-1}$(x)), which is equal to ${g}^{-1}$∘${f}^{-1}$.

Your insights and your proof is correct but the answers below may help you write a cleaner proof.

Why are you using $a,b,c$ which are specific values rather than general variables?  The argument is the same but by only arguing for $a,b,c$ you've only proved it for those values.

Are you assuming $(f\circ g)^{-1}$ exists in the first place?  Do you know $f^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}$ exist?

To add to the (fully correct) answer already posted, in better notation what you have proved is that $(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ (f\circ g)(a)=a$ for an arbitrary $a$, which is a good start!
I would encourage you to clean up your proof by using these facts:

That function composition is associative, that is, $f\circ(g\circ h) = (f\circ g)\circ h$ for all functions $f,g,h$
That by definition $f\circ f^{-1}=f^{-1}\circ f = e$ for all functions $f$, where $e(x)=x$ is the identity function, which means that it has the property $f\circ e = e \circ f = f$

And don't forget to prove the defining inverse property both ways, that is, you are trying to prove that $(f\circ g)\circ(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})=e$ and $(g^{-1}\circ f^{-1})\circ (f\circ g) = e$

This is not a sufficient proof. If you want to prove something in math, you always want to appeal back to formal definitions and theorems to make it rigorous. Here, for instance, it would be greatly helpful to appeal to the formal definition of an inverse.
In algebra, an element is considered the inverse of another element iff they combine (under the group operation) to form the identity element. More formally, $a$ and $b$ are inverses of each other iff $ab = ba = e$.
Now in your case, the identity element $e$ is just considered the identity function. So if you want to show that $(f \circ g)^{-1} = g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}$, you would need to show that $(f \circ g)(g^{-1} \circ f^{-1}) = e$ and that $(g^{-1} \circ f^{-1})(f \circ g) = e$, where $e$ is the identity function. I'll leave that up to you to finish.

In the first place, you are implicitly assuming that $f$ and $g$ are bijections (as otherwise an inverse wouldn't even exist) between (equipotent) sets, say $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Z\to V$. Moreover:

for "$fg$" to make sense, $V\stackrel{(g\text{ bijection})}{=}g(Z)\subseteq X$ must hold, and
for "$g^{-1}f^{-1}$" to make sense, $X\stackrel{(f^{-1}\text{ bijection})}{=}f^{-1}(Y)\subseteq V$ must hold.

Therefore, $X\stackrel{\text{from 2}}{\subseteq} V\stackrel{\text{from 1}}{\subseteq} X$, and hence $V=X$. So, your setting is sensible iff $f$ and $g$ are bijections $f\colon X\to Y$ and $g\colon Z\to X$.
Seeminlgy all this you took for granted, but I think it's worthwhile to mention.
That clarified, you can prove your claim by an "iff chain", where the final step is an identity (trivially true). For example (hereafter $\iota_S$ stands for the identity map of any set $S$, namely $\iota_S(s)=s$ for every $s\in S$):
\begin{alignat}{1}
&(fg)^{-1}=g^{-1}f^{-1}&&\iff \\
&(fg)(fg)^{-1}=(fg)(g^{-1}f^{-1})&&\iff \\
&\iota_Y=f(gg^{-1})f^{-1}&&\iff\\
&\iota_Y=f\iota_Xf^{-1}&&\iff\\
&\iota_Y=ff^{-1}&&\iff\\
&\iota_Y=\iota_Y\\
\end{alignat}
Or, equivalently:
\begin{alignat}{1}
&(fg)^{-1}=g^{-1}f^{-1}&&\iff \\
&(fg)^{-1}(fg)=(g^{-1}f^{-1})(fg)&&\iff \\
&\iota_Z=g^{-1}(f^{-1}f)g&&\iff\\
&\iota_Z=g^{-1}\iota_Xg&&\iff\\
&\iota_Z=g^{-1}g&&\iff\\
&\iota_Z=\iota_Z\\
\end{alignat}
(Can you see why the "only if" direction in the first "$\iff$" of the two blocks does hold?)
